# mysql Error code 1452 while inserting into tables

Tags: mysql-workbench

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL ,
  `Gender` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `FirstName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Major` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ContactInfo` longtext,
  `ApartmentID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_STUDENT_RESIDENCE_idx` (`ApartmentID`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_STUDENT_RESIDENCE` FOREIGN KEY (`ApartmentID`) REFERENCES `residence` (`ApartmentID`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

Untill this everything is executed after that when i am trying to insert i am geting error code 1452

```
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (1,'','John','Choo','Economics','Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia',1), 
  (2,'','Albert','Sipaling','Marketing','Jakarta, Indonesia',1),   
  (3,'\0','Irene','Choo','Software','Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia',2);
```

Answer (score 0):

As in create table says

```
CONSTRAINT FK_STUDENT_RESIDENCE FOREIGN KEY (ApartmentID) REFERENCES residence (ApartmentID)
```

you have a reference to another table "residence"

Just be sure that  ApartmentID that you are inserting into students exists in residence before this insert.

Answer (score 0):

I think try passing null value to the gender on your 3rd data row........

```
INSERT INTO student VALUES (1,'','John','Choo','Economics','Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia',1),(2,'','Albert','Sipaling','Marketing','Jakarta, Indonesia',1),(3,'','Irene','Choo','Software','Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia',2);
```